# App status on Play Console is Available but Supported Devices 0

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I just trying to publish my android app, now my app status is Available on Play Store, but when I search in play store my app is not found.
When I check the release details in the Google Play console, I see devices supported by my app are zero. Any reason why this happened??

This is our manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.ourteam.ourapp">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="29" />
<!--    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />-->
<!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.legacy" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
<!--custom permission device-->
<uses-permission android:name="com.vivo.permissionmanager" />
<uses-permission android:name="oppo.permission.OPPO_COMPONENT_SAFE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.permission.external_app_settings.USE_COMPONENT" />
<!--custom permission device end-->
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.zxing.client.android" />
<queries>
    <!-- Browser -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
    </intent>

    <!-- Camera -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
    </intent>
    <!-- Gallery -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
    </intent>
</queries>
<application
    android:name=".modul.GlobalClass"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
    tools:targetApi="n">
    <uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false" />
    <!--        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="@string/google_api_key" />-->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="blabla" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/notification_channel_id" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/orangePrimaryLightest" />

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.ourteam.ourapp.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        tools:replace="android:authorities">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_path" />
    </provider>
    <service
        android:name=".firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:stopWithTask="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!--add firebase activity API require 32-->
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"
        tools:node="merge" />
    
    <service
        android:name=".ourTask.TaskServices"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
        android:stopWithTask="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ACTION_CALL" />
            <action android:name="ACTION_SETTING" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <receiver
        android:name=".ourTask.TaskReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
        tools:node="merge">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="ALARMSETTING" />
            <action android:name="ALARMCALL" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    

    <activity
        android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
        android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    
</application>
```

I tried looking this problem up online but I couldn't find a problem similar to mine. Most apps have no supported devices because they use features that are only available in some or in no devices. I just can't figure out what's wrong in mine. I've actually tested this app on my device and it worked fine

Comment: btw, `<uses-feature "x"` means for the playstore "requires feature X" which will make it unavailable to devices that don't have that. Make them optional if you don't actually require all of them. There's a `"required"`  flag you can put in there.

Answer (score 0):

### **Answer 1**

Have you waited 24 hours? It can take some time for the app to get uploaded to ALL Google's servers.

### Answer 2

Have you added devices? You navigate to 'YOUR_APP' > Reach And Devices > Device Catalog. Then you click the Manage Devices > Include Devices. Then you select the devices you support.

[image: Example]

Then:

[image: Then Do This]